# Aggregate function in SQL Update query

Tags: sql-server

I have table Emp which consists of 4 columns;

```
Name   Date        Calls  Supervisor
Alwin  10-05-2016  20     Pramod
Pavan  11-05-2016  10     Steevan
Amit   12-05-2016  12     Raja
Alwin  13-05-2016  15     Sagar
```

We need to add up the calls of all users and place them under the most recent date and the respective Supervisor and we need only one row per user.
The expected result what we looking for is

```
Name   Date        Calls  Supervisor
Pavan  11-05-2016  10     Steevan
Amit   12-05-2016  12     Raja
Alwin  13-05-2016  35     Sagar
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you also post the expected result?

Comment: What do you mean by "Username should update to Recent added supervisor" ?

Comment: If table consist same username twice for different supervisor, in result based on recent date username should consider supervisor & sum up calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM() Over` to find the total `calls` per `Name` and to get the `supervisor` based on latest `date` use `Row_Number()` window function

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT NAME, 
                date, 
                Sum(calls)OVER(partition BY NAME)  AS calls, 
                supervisor, 
                Row_number()OVER(partition BY NAME ORDER BY date DESC) Rn 
         FROM   yourtable) 
SELECT NAME, 
       date, 
       calls, 
       supervisor 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
select Name, Date, SUM(Calls) from Test
Group By Name, Date
```

Result:

```
Name    Date        SumCalls
Alwin   05/10/2016  35
Pavan   05/11/2016  10
Amit    05/12/2016  12
```

Comment: I don't think this address the `Supervisor` in result